# Combine multiple module mocks in Jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I have multiple files I have to mock in a test file, which looks quite unsightly and was wondering if they can be combined, or looped through and set? Or how would you organise the file?

```
jest.mock('path/to/module/one', () = 'mockModuleOne');
jest.mock('path/to/module/two', () = 'mockModuleTwo');
jest.mock('path/to/module/three', () = 'mockModuleThree');
// etc etc x 10

// Eventually test describe blocks
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
jest.mock([{
  'path/to/module/one': () = 'mockModuleOne',
  'path/to/module/two': () = 'mockModuleTwo'
}]);
```

I tried creating an array of file paths and names to loop and set the mock, but jest didn't like that by flagging: `The module factory of jest.mock() is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.`

Comment: No, you can't. And you can't write helper function because it wouldn't be hoisted like jest.mock. Use `__mocks__` if you can.

Comment: Thanks Estus, yeah thought as much but just wanted to make sure!! Thank you